# IBM DB2 administration server already active , but says not

Tags: database, db2

I am working with IBM db2 v 9.7.I tried creating a DDL script using the Control Center , it gives an error saying the db admin server is inactive.However,when i tried starting it using db2admin start from cmd processor it says,its already active.
What is actually happening?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: what are the connection parameters you're using?

Comment: Afaik , the Control Center does not ask for any connection parameters

Comment: @nikel you should read this post from IBM about [Control Center tools are deprecated](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fi0054250.html)

Answer (score 2):

Can you please confirm if the below services in your services.msc list are started?

1. DB2 Remote Command Server
2. DB2 Management Service

Answer (score 1):

When I try to create database from **Control Center** I get the same error but when I try to create db from **Command Line** it works!

[image]

Comment: yeah...even i tried this way.CMD works  ; but i can't resort to CMD for everything

Comment: You must only create database from cmd. You can do everything other from control center

Comment: but other things like creating DDL for a database again give the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Recreate DAS services using below Commands . It will help

db2admin stop , 
db2admin drop, 
db2admin create,
db2admin start